# what is right? dbcp/dbcp2/tomcat validation-query

Tags: java, spring-boot, connection, datasource

I need create connection reconect in Spring boot. Many examples shows like this:

```
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

but Intellij IDE not see ths and shows:

```
spring.datasource.dbcp.validation-query=select 1
```

and

```
spring.datasource.dbcp2.validation-query=select 1
```

and

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=select 1
```

what is right?

Comment: Which is right, depends on the Spring Boot versions < 1.3 the first, > 1.3 the last.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before Spring 1.4, all connection pool providers (Tomcat, Apache DBCP, Apache DBCP v2, Hikari, ...) used the same properties, for example:

```
spring.datasource.validationQuery=select 1
```

Depending on the connection pool vendor, you could use different properties. Not only that, but some of those properties weren't used to configure the vendor-specific properties, but were used by Spring boot as well. So they were quite [ambiguous](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2183).

Since 1.4 the Spring boot properties are within `spring.datasource.*` while the connection pool properties are within `spring.datasource.tomcat.*` or `spring.datasource.dbcp.*` or ... .

---

To answer your question, if you're using Spring boot 1.3 or less the correct answer is:

```
spring.datasource.validationQuery=select 1
```

If you're using Spring boot 1.4 or newer with the default tomcat-jdbc connection pool, the correct answer is:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.validationQuery=select 1
```

The other options you provided are only valid if you're using Spring boot 1.4 or newer and did override the default connection pool provider.

---

Other than that you can choose whether or not you want to use camelcase (`validationQuery`) or kebab-case (`validation-query`), both work fine on any version of Spring boot.

Comment: or spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1